# How to format this obscure character vector into datetime (or POSIX) objects in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following character vector:

```r
times <- c("2020-04-15T03:30:05.197Z", "2020-04-15T03:30:05.366Z", "2020-04-15T03:30:05.530Z")
```

I need to first convert it to a `lubridate` datetime object or a POSIXct object - I'm not picky. The following does not work:

```r
as_datetime(link_log$createdAt,
            format = "%Y-%m-%d%T%H:%M:%S")
```

To be honest, I'm not sure what's going on with the end of each element. What is the .197Z, .366Z, .530Z? I am assuming these are the problem!

Comment: No, they are standard formats for which you _could_ use a common input format, see `help(strptime)`.  Or ... just use `anytime()`.

Comment: The end of the timestamp is its timezone. Z stands for Zulu time zone

Comment: @camille this is so helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lubridate`'s `ymd_hms` seems to work.

```
options(digits.secs=6)
lubridate::ymd_hms(times)

#[1] "2020-04-15 03:30:05.197 UTC" "2020-04-15 03:30:05.366 UTC" 
#    "2020-04-15 03:30:05.529 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

The [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package was written to make this automatic: no need for format strings or conversions:

```
R> times <- c("2020-04-15T03:30:05.197Z", "2020-04-15T03:30:05.366Z", 
+             "2020-04-15T03:30:05.530Z")
R> anytime::anytime(times)
[1] "2020-04-15 03:30:05.197 CDT" "2020-04-15 03:30:05.365 CDT" 
[3] "2020-04-15 03:30:05.529 CDT"
R>
```

You can pass in character or factor or numeric or ... formats, and as long as the format is sensible and common (i.e. we ignore two-digit years) it should work. It even allows for *different* formats. It also runs faster than most alternatives requiring a format or hint.